# Get value from Dynamic input

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to get the value from dynamically created field in my app using a branch in Oracle Apex with PL/SQL. I have tried to fetch it like other fields with `:NAME` and i had no luck. My code from branch looks like this,

```
DECLARE
    tabs    INTEGER := :P2_CREATE_TABS;
    lines    INTEGER := :P2_LINES;
    counter NUMBER := 1;
    content VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EmailContent (CUSTOMERNAME, ORGANISATIONNUMBER, CONTACTNUMBER, EMAIL)
    VALUES (:P2_CUST_NAME, :P2_ORG_NUM, :P2_CONTACT_NUM, :P2_EMAIL);    
    FOR tab_counter IN 1 .. tabs
    LOOP
        FOR line_count IN 1 .. lines
        LOOP
            FOR element_count IN 1 .. 3
            LOOP
                IF(counter < 10) THEN
                    content := :F||0||counter;
                    INSERT INTO DynamicContent (ID_EMAIL, ID_TAB, ID_LINE, CONTENTVALUE)
                    VALUES
                        (
                            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmailContent),
                             tab_counter,
                             line_count,
                             content
                        );
                    counter := counter + 1;
                ELSE
                    content := :F||counter;
                    INSERT INTO DynamicContent (ID_EMAIL, ID_TAB, ID_LINE, CONTENTVALUE)
                    VALUES
                        (
                            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmailContent),
                             tab_counter,
                             line_count,
                             content
                        );
                    counter := counter + 1;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
        counter := 0;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Fields are created with `APEX_ITEM.TEXT(...` which has `p_idx` which generates F01, F02, ..., F50 and that's why i have tried to use `content := :F||0||counter;` and `content := :F||counter;`.

With this outcome, my database it's populated with values 01, 02, 03, ..., 00, 01...etc. And i want to fetch the value from input with name FXX.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12510/apex_app.htm#AEAPI216

Comment: Thank you @romeuBraga , this helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @romeuBraga

Since fields were created dynamically with `APEX_ITEM.TEXT(...` the p_idx generates F with range 01-50 and this can be used as array. Can be accessed like this `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i);`.